# Notification.Builder does not create a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

Im trying to create a notification from an edittext and broadcast receiver. In my first Activity the user should input a message and push the broadcast button. I want to take that string and create a notification from it and open a new activity that displays the message. I am doing all the notification work in my broadcast receiver class.
I have looked around onlne at examples and other peoples code but im not sure what im not getting right. The application loads up just fine and the broadcast button sends the broadcast to the receiver and Logs the string but the notification is never created.
Thanks for any help.

Broadcast class that sends broadcast message:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverActivity extends Activity
{
EditText et;
Button btn1;
public static String BString = "HappyHemingway";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_broadcast_receiver);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           String message = et.getText().toString();
           send(message);
        }
    });
}

/*
* This function creates an intent and
* sends a broadcast from the message
* parameter passed in.
*/
protected void send(String msg)
{
    Log.i("msg", msg);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("message",msg);
    i.setAction(BString);
    sendBroadcast(i);

}
}
```

Receiver class that creates notification:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
// @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action!=null&&action.equals("HappyHemingway"))
    {

        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.i("Received",msg);

        Intent i = new Intent(context,ViewNotification.class);
        i.putExtra("message",msg);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context).
                setSmallIcon(0).setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(msg).
                setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setContentTitle("New Notification!").
                setContentText(msg).setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification n = builder.build();
        mgr.notify(0, n);
        Log.i("Received again",msg);

    }
 }
 }
```

notification viewer class that is never launched

```
public class ViewNotification extends Activity
{

String text; 
TextView txttext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewnotification);


    NotificationManager notificationmanager;
    notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationmanager.cancel(0);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    text = i.getStringExtra("message");
    txttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txttext.setText(text);
    Log.i("made it", "made it made it made it");
}

}
```

manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiverActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewNotification"></activity>
    <receiver android:name="Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="HappyHemingway">
                    </action>
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Hopefully its just a simple error I'm overlooking.This is my first time using Android Studio instead of Eclipse but I dont see how that could make any difference under than my unfamiliarity with the IDE.
Anything helps
thanks.

Comment: I´m not sure but I think the problem could be, that You are directly cancel the message when the Activity is started. Try to comment out the notificationmanager.cancel(0); just for testing.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt change anything. The class ViewNotification is still never reached. Thanks though.

Comment: but You are sure that the broadcast is reached?

Comment: ok.....saw Your answer too late...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I had setSmallIcon(0.)
When I changed it to setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) everything worked fine.